# Documentation link for "improvement requests" not showing the correct requests

Tags: bug, documentation

I was trying to go through the improvement requests in the Microsoft SQL Server topic, and found some weird behavior. If you click the "2 improvement requests" in the `GROUP BY` topic in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics?page=2&tab=popular), it shows me "0 Improvements Requested for GROUP BY":

[image]

[image]

Now, that's weird enough, but if you click in the "need improvement" tab, it shows me 2 improvement requests, but for another topic (Database Snapshot):

[image]